# Shell expansion with heredoc

Tags: bash

How does one for subshell expansion in heredoc for all command?

eg:

```
file=report_$(date +%Y%m%d)
cat <<EOF > $file
    date
    hostname
    echo 'End of Report'
EOF
```

such that all the commands are evaluated?

I am aware

```
file=report_$(date +%Y%m%d)
cat <<EOF > $file
    $(date))
    $(hostname)
    $(echo 'End of Report')
EOF
```

would work, but is there a way to specify subshell by default?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `sh` (or `bash`) as the command instead of `cat`; that will actually run it as shell script:

```
sh <<EOF > $file
    date
    hostname
    echo 'End of Report'
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to expand all lines as commands, heredoc is useless:

```
file="report_$(date +%Y%m%d)"
{
  date
  hostname
  echo 'End of Report'
} >| "$file"
```

You may also redirect `1>` like that:

```
file="report_$(date +%Y%m%d)"
exec 1> "$file"
date
hostname
echo 'End of Report'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not like that, but:

```
cat << EOF | sh > $file
    date
    hostname
    echo 'End of Report'
EOF
```

would achieve the same result.  (Note that this is a new `sh` command—use `bash` if desired—and not a subshell of the current shell, so it does not have the same variables set.)

(Edit: I failed to note that this is also a UUOC: a Useless Use Of Cat; see Explosion Pills' answer. :-) )

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me; it seems to think that the heredoc is unclosed

Comment: two pretty good answers, but Explosion Pills seems _slightly_ more straightforward

Comment: @torek I just copied yours; maybe a different shell version

Comment: @Lighthart people always seem to forget that there is no difference reading stdin from the shell as from a pipe; I often see things like `cat file | cut` when `cut file` does the same thing.

Comment: @ExplosionPills: looks like cut and paste stuck some extra white space in somehow (before the "EOF" bit).  I'd blame cat-on-keyboard but she wasn't here when I was typing that... :-)

Comment: @torek oh, obviously that was it.  I should have seen that myself ><