# Shell Script to execute SQL Queries

Tags: sql, shell

I have 2 SQL queries which I execute to get the size of table and number of records in a table

```
[~] mysql -u <username> -h <hostname> -p <db_name> -e "SQL_Query 1" > out.txt
```

```
[~] mysql -u <username> -h <hostname> -p <db_name> -e "SQL_Query 2" > out1.txt
```

How can I wite shell script to execute these queries

Comment: This could be considered a duplicate related to any of the shell / heredoc posts.  mysql ... <<EOF ... heredoc contents ... EOF.  `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453966/shell-expansion-with-heredoc`

Answer (score 0):

This is a shell script, supported by bash / sh, and probably others:

```
#!/bin/sh
mysql -u <username> -h <hostname> -p > output.log <<EOF
SELECT query 1 ...;
SELECT query 2 ...;
EOF
```

Note: You'll need to address the password entry issue, which can be done in several ways.

You can also enter your SQL in a file (file.sql) and redirect input from that file:

```
mysql -u <username> -h <hostname> -p < file.sql > output.log
```

Comment: this should be in .sh file ? where will output be stored

Comment: Yes.  sh / bash supports this, and maybe a few others.